# When cross-joining 3 or more tables, is redundant row data transferred and using up DB bandwidth in Entity Framework?

Tags: sql, entity-framework

Suppose I have 4 tables: `Posts`, `Likes`, `Comments` and `Files`. Now I'd like to select all likes, comments, and files for a particular post, say using LINQ in Entity Framework. This is easy, just do something like this:

```
var post = m_dbContext.Posts
                      .Include(x => x.Likes)
                      .Include(x => x.Comments.OrderBy(c => c.CreatedAt))
                      .Include(x => x.Files)
                      .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
```

Now suppose that our post has 100 like records, 10 comments, and 5 files. The result from the database will have 100x10x5 = 5k rows. Notably, all selected file records will be duplicated for each combination of like and comment. This can be confirmed by performing this query in SQL viewer.

Finally, let's assume that each file record is 100kB worth of data on average (say a base64-encoded string).

Does this mean that when the above query is performed, the database will have to transfer upwards of 5k x 100kB = 500 MB worth of data over the network from the database to the server due to the row "redundancy" caused by joins? Or are there some smarts behind the curtain where the database sends non-redundant data and Entity Framework will reconstruct it? When I preform the query manually, I just get 5k rows in the UI.

Where can I learn more about this issue?

**UPDATE**

Here is more about this issue: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/single-split-queries#performance-issues-with-single-queries

> This means that if a given blog has 10 posts and 10 contributors, the database returns 100 rows for that single blog. This phenomenon - sometimes called cartesian explosion - can cause huge amounts of data to unintentionally get transferred to the client, especially as more sibling JOINs are added to the query; this can be a major performance issue in database applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It depends if you are using [Split Queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/single-split-queries) or not.** This depends on your global Configuration as well as per-query usage of `AsSplitQuery()` as documented.

EF will transform your query, along with its `Include`s, into an SQL statement. It is then up to the server as to how to process that statement.

If you are not using Split Queries then you get a cartesian cross-join as you suspected, which can be highly inefficient. There are some situations where it's better though: for example if the various joins are not well indexed.

You would need to check the actual SQL being executed, but I would expect something similar to:

```sql
SELECT
  p.*,
  l.*,
  c.*,
  f.*
FROM (
    SELECT TOP (1)
      p.*
    FROM Posts p
    WHERE p.Id = @id
) p
JOIN Likes l ON ...
JOIN Comments c ON ...
JOIN Files f ON ...
ORDER BY c.CreatedAt;
```

You should check the query plan for that to ensure it is efficent. If, as you suspect, the query is just a giant join, then in your case it will be slow.

If you were using split queries, which is the default in modern versions of EF, then you would get four separate `SELECT` queries, one for each table, but assuming good indexing then this would be much more efficient as it avoids the cartesian cross-join.

To ensure you get a split query no matter your EF Core Configuration, you can use `.AsSplitQuery()`. You can enable it globally as follows

```cs
optionsBuilder
    .UseSqlServer(
            @"SomeConnectionStringHere",
            o => o.UseQuerySplittingBehavior(QuerySplittingBehavior.SplitQuery));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am not using split query, but my question was mostly about "if this is executed as a single big query with joins, will the redundant data actually be transferred over the network?" If the answer is "yes", then of course I can split the query, manually or automatically via `AsSplitQuery`.

Comment: Then yes, of course, the SQL generated is what is executed, so if that's a cartesian product then it will be larger than necesssary.